# Does smarttable provide with single row editing?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a simple Fiori app which displays a smarttable for now. I have to implement an additional feature to it, that enables single row editing in the UI. The changes have to be captured and reflected back to the backend. 
Can single row editing be implemented on the smarttable control? 
If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For editable scenarios with backend metadata/field controls, using SmartFields in the SmartTable might provide you with what you're looking for. 
You can let the SmartTable automatically create SmartFields using:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="ItemsST" entitySet="Items" customData:useSmartField="true"...>
```

This is assuming that the view has the custom data namespace declared correctly, to enable UI5 shortcut notation for custom data aggregations:

```
xmlns:customData=http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1
```

If you use the editable Smart Table, then you also should set the property        **editable="true**".

In addition, you can use **editTogglable="true"** in order to be able to switch between edit and display mode as user.